# Жизненный цикл ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel

Судя по документации, `ViewModel` переживает вызов метода `onDestroy()` при изменении конфигурации, но вызов метода `onDestroy()` после вызова `finish()` означает конец жизненного цикла `ViewModel`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А каким образом Android фреймворк определяет, после какого `onDestroy()` нужно убить `ViewModel`, а после какого - оставить жить? Именно вызов `finish()` является главным критерием?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думается мне в вашем вопросе читается и ответ.

Если Активити уничтожается при смене конфигурации, то ViewModel продолжает жить. Если Система уничтожает Активити согласно приоритетам, то уничтожается и ViewModel связанная с этим Активити.

[Читаем](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle)

> The ViewModel exists from when you first request a ViewModel until the
>   activity is finished and destroyed.

[Также](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#2)

> **Caution**: The scope of an activity or fragment goes from created to
>   finished (or terminated), which you must not confuse with destroyed.
>   Remember that when a device is rotated, the activity is destroyed but
>   any instances of ViewModel associated with it are not.

Comment: Спасибо! Начала искать, чем отличаются состояния активити finished (terminated) и destroyed. Нашла тут: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
"You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method".